# Javascript bookmarklet to pull multiple pieces of information and open a new tab with a search using that information

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

A colleague (who has now sadly left) has helped me build a number of bookmarklets in the past, which enable me to search other sites using information from a CRM we use (pipedrive). I've tried to combine two bookmarklets to create a new one, but it doesn't work despite all my troubleshooting (I have absolutely no knowledge of javascript or bookmarklets bar editing the ones my colleague created.)

These two bookmarklets work just fine:

> javascript: void (function() { const list =
> Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('span.relatedItemContainer'));
> const i = list.length - 2; var person =
> list[i].innerText.split(',')[0]; if (!person) {person = prompt("Unable
> to automatically detect. Enter school name:")}; if (person)
> {window.open("https://app.intercom.com/a/apps/q6mpres8/users/segments/all-users?searchTerm=" + encodeURI(person) )}; })();

> javascript: void (function() { const list = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('span.relatedItemContainer')); const i = list.length - 2; var person = list[i].innerText.split(',')[0]; if (!person) {person = prompt("Unable to automatically detect. Enter school name:")}; if (person) {window.open("https://app.intercom.com/a/apps/q6mpres8/users/segments/all-users?searchTerm=" + encodeURI(person) )}; })();

Now I want to use **both** the person and school constants to create a google search to find that person, from that school, on Linkedin. To do this, I tried combining the queries in all sorts of ways but no luck. The below is what I've currently ended up with having read a bunch of other questions on here and tried editing all different bits.

> javascript: void (function() { const list = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('span.relatedItemContainer')); const i = list.length - 2 , j = list.length - 1; var person = list[i].innerText.split(',')[0] , school = list[j].innerText.split(',')[0;]; if (person && school) {window.open("https://www.google.com/search?q=linked+in+" + encodeURI(person) + “+” + encodeURI(school))}; })();

Any help on what I'm missing appreciated.

Comment: 1. You've got `[0;]`, but it should have been `[0]`
2. It seems like you have an extra `)` bracket at the end.
3. `, school` instead of `; var school`

What input does it give?
Will this work for you?

`javascript: void (function() { const list = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('span.relatedItemContainer')); const i = list.length - 2 , j = list.length - 1; var person = list[i].innerText.split(',')[0]; var school = list[j].innerText.split(',')[0]; if (person && school) {window.open("https://www.google.com/search?q=linked+in+" + encodeURI(person) + “+” + encodeURI(school)}; })();`

Comment: Thanks for your help ZolVas but unfortunately that script still doesn't open a window so I've got no way of identifying the issue is.